# Is the deploying of the contract anonymous?

Tags: contract-deployment, opcode

Is the deploying of the contract anonymous? is it possible to find the owner who posted the contract? Is the only mention of it a link to the wallet from which the smart contract was first replenished or gas was paid?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The address that deploys the contract is recorded on the blockchain and can be viewed by anyone with access to a blockchain explorer or other tools that allow them to interact with the blockchain.

Having the Bored Ape Yacht Club smart contract, we can get [the deployment transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x22199329b0aa1aa68902a78e3b32ca327c872fab166c7a2838273de6ad383eba) and get all the details (including the address of deployer).

Comment: thanks for the answer, and what other data becomes visible? what site or program is viewing it?

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Once the contract is deployed you can see the smart contract code + functions are avalible to interact with

Comment: @VX3 could you pl specify direction of investigate or source of this knowledge. thx

Comment: Have a look at this youtube guide on [How to use Etherscan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spnwIsE5ziQ&ab_channel=bfresh) and after that you can check the [Etherscan documentation](https://docs.etherscan.io/) for more.

Comment: Hi @newbeee - the data is visible on the blockchain and you can use something like Etherscan to view the data - the blockchain is accessible to all